# How can I change from collection view to table view by selected scope?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview, uisearchbar

Hi I have a ViewController with inside a Search bar with scope on top and a collection view. When I change scope from "scope1" to "scope2" I want to replace CollectionView with Tableview. Is it possibile?

[image: Image of My Controller]

Comment: Yes, this is possible using container views: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have both yourCollectionView and yourTableView on the same ViewController and hide or show them according to your selection. Like this:

```
if scope1 {
    yourCollectionView.isHidden = false 
    yourTableView.isHidden = true
} else {
    yourCollectionView.isHidden = true 
    yourTableView.isHidden = false
}
```

But have in mind that depending on what you want to do in your ViewController, this behaviour can become tricky to track, so you might wanna check out the possibility of using [Container View](https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers).